# mysqli Too Many Connections - try to connect again?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a host that supports only 25 mysql connections per time. I can't change it. Everyday I see an error log in my host about this.

```
[21-Jul-2016 02:14:05 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (42000/1203): User s already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in /home/s/public_html/config.php on line 8
[21-Jul-2016 02:14:05 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  mysqli::set_charset(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/s/public_html/config.php on line 9
```

So I was thinking about some php solution.

I want to get this error when it happens and make user wait some seconds and try again after it! maybe it can do a header location to a page and this page can call a js to do this.

my php connection

```
$mysqli2 = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $pass, $bd);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 // how to check if it is the MAX CONNECTION ERROR?
}
```

how can I check if the error is the max connection?
is it a good solution? is it gonna work? any other ideas?

Comment: you are close it or not  (mysqli_close) ??

Comment: or, create a persistent connection?

Comment: If you use the same details connections  are shared

Comment: @devodedra I'm not using musqli_close in my php files... it closes at the end of the php, doesn't it?

Comment: I use something like this to connect @hjpotter92:  `$stmt = $mysqli2->prepare("SELECT cover, titulo, visitas from posts WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($cover, $titulo, $visitas);
$stmt->fetch(); $stmt->close();`

Comment: @Dagon I use the same in all pages to connect. is it a problem?

Comment: Someone needs a connection pool. Opening it for each page is ridiculously slow.

Comment: @tadman can you give me an example how to do this? i include the config.php to connect at the top of each php script... is it wrong?

Comment: If only there was some kind of internet service where you could type in keywords like "mysqli connection pool" and get pages [like this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php). The first person to do that is going to be crazy rich, I'm not even kidding.

Comment: @tadman thank you very much! so, in config.php I need to add p: and it is done?

Comment: If you can figure out the details and can confirm they solve your problem, add an answer here so other people can learn from your findings.